# Show / Hide selectinput in R shiny based on conditions

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to use conditions to show or hide selectinputs in a R shiny app based if the tab is available in the UI or not. So on tabpanel with title `product use` then all the drop downs under product category should be seen else only the first dropdown under product category should be visible.

Below is what I am doing but not getting the condition to work:

```html
# This is the server logic for a Shiny web application.
# You can find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
# http://shiny.rstudio.com
#
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyBS)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(disable = F, title = "PATH Study"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "wave",
      h4("Wave"),
      choices = list(
        "Wave 1" = 1
      ),
      selected = 1
    ),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(
        "Population Filter",
        selectInput(
          "ethnicity",
          h4("Ethnicity"),
          choices = list(
            "Hispanic" = 1,
            "Asian" = 2,
            "White" = 3,
            "African American" = 4
          ),
          selected = 1
        ),
        selectInput(
          "age",
          h4("Age Group"),
          choices = list(
            "Total" = 1,
            "Youth(12-17)" = 2,
            "Young Adult (18-24)" = 3,
            "Adult (25+)" = 4
          ),
          selected = 1
        ),
        selectInput(
          "category",
          h4("Gender"),
          choices = list(
            "Total" = 1,
            "Male" = 2,
            "Female" = 3
          ),
          selected = 1
        )
      )
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "dashboardBody(tabPanel(title  == 'product_use'))",
      sidebarMenu(menuItem(
        "Product Category",
        selectInput(
          "category",
          h4("Category"),
          choices = list(
            "Total Cigars" = 1,
            "Cigarillo" = 2,
            "Cigarette" = 3,
            "E-Vapor" = 4
          ),
          selected = 1
        ),
        selectInput(
          "flavor",
          h4("Flavor"),
          choices = list(
            "Total" = 1,
            "Flavored" = 2,
            "Non-Flavored" = 3
          ),
          selected = 1
        ),
        selectInput(
          "use_level",
          h4("User Level"),
          choices = list(
            "Total" = 1,
            "Experimental" = 2,
            "Established" = 3,
            "No Tobacco Use" = 4
          ),
          selected = 1
        )
      ))
    )
    
    
  ),
  #S dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(), sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),body,title = NUll, skin = "yellow"),
  dashboardBody(box(
    width = 12,
    tabBox(
      width = 12,
      id = "tabBox_next_previous",
      tabPanel("Initiation",
               fluidRow(
                 box(
                   title = "Wave 1 Ever Tried and % 1st Product Flavored",
                   width = 5,
                   solidHeader = TRUE,
                   status = "primary",
                   tableOutput("smoke"),
                   collapsible = F,
                   bsTooltip(
                     "bins",
                     "The wait times will be broken into this many equally spaced bins",
                     "right",
                     options = list(container = "body")
                   )
                 )
                     )),

      tabPanel("Cessation", p("This is tab 3")),
      tabPanel("product_use", p("This is tab 4")),
      tags$script(
        "
        $('body').mouseover(function() {
        list_tabs=[];
        $('#tabBox_next_previous li a').each(function(){
        list_tabs.push($(this).html())
        });
        Shiny.onInputChange('List_of_tab', list_tabs);})
        "
      )
    ),
    
    uiOutput("Next_Previous")
  ))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Next_Previous = renderUI({
    tab_list = input$List_of_tab[-length(input$List_of_tab)]
    nb_tab = length(tab_list)
    if (which(tab_list == input$tabBox_next_previous) == nb_tab)
      column(1, offset = 1, Previous_Button)
    else if (which(tab_list == input$tabBox_next_previous) == 1)
      column(1, offset = 10, Next_Button)
    else
      div(column(1, offset = 1, Previous_Button),
          column(1, offset = 8, Next_Button))
    
  })
  
  output$smoke <-
    
    #   renderTable({
    #   pct_ever_user(data_selector(wave = 1, youth = FALSE), type = "SM")
    # })
    
    function() {
      pct_ever_user(data_selector(wave = 1, youth = FALSE), type = "SM")[, c("variable", "mean", "sum_wts", "se")] %>%
        # rename(pct_ever_user(data_selector(wave = 1, youth = FALSE), type = "SM"), c("mean"="N", "sum_wts"="Weighted N"))%>%
        knitr::kable("html") %>%
        kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
    }
  
  output$table2 <- function() {
    # req(input$mpg)
    table2 %>%
      knitr::kable("html") %>%
      kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive"))
  }
  output$consumption <- function() {
    # req(input$mpg)
    consumption %>%
      knitr::kable("html") %>%
      kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
  }
  output$consumption_flav <- function() {
    # req(input$mpg)
    consumption_flav %>%
      knitr::kable("html") %>%
      kable_styling("striped", full_width = F)
  }
  
  
}



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the Product Category menu to show up when you are on the product_use tab, you can set your condition to the following:

```
condition = "input.tabBox_next_previous  == 'product_use'",
```

From `?conditionalPanel`:

> *condition*
>   A JavaScript expression that will be evaluated repeatedly to determine whether the panel should be displayed.
>
> In the JS expression, you can refer to input and output JavaScript objects that contain the current values of input and output. For example, if you have an input with an id of foo, then you can use input.foo to read its value. (Be sure not to modify the input/output objects, as this may cause unpredictable behavior.)

Comment: Actually I want product category menu to show up always. But the two select inputs under that menu to show up only when tab == product_use